# Проблема с слиянием двух веток в одну

Tags: git, github

Мы работаем командой из нескольких человек, занимаемся на Unity. Гитом я до этого работал хорошо, когда писал именно сайты, потому что там только код и легко делать merge. Здесь же я столкнулся с родом проблем. Делал я всё как обычно создавал ветки от мастера. Вот создали мы 5 веток от мастера и пришла пора их слить, и допустим с первой веткой прошло всё отлично так как она первая. Но пошёл слиять вторую ветку, а у этого второго человека нет же изменений которые есть на мастере, так как я только что сделал мердж первой ветки и в итоге все файлы первой ветки при слиянии второй ветки удалились. Не трудно догадаться, что если я делаю мердж третьей ветки, то дропаются файлы второй и в итоге получается вообще не понятно что. Можно ли как-то мерджить эти ветки, но чтобы файлы не удалялись загруженные ранее? Что я не так делаю? Там ещё проблема будет, что на одной сцене работает 3 человека для быстрой работы и там наверное уже гг будет.
Есть ли какие-то программы, которые помогают мерджить Юнити проекты, потому что я делаю через git Desctope

Comment: Надо делать `rebase`/`merge` с текущим `master`-ом перед слитием. Но я бы советовал смотреть https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/.

Comment: @tocic - не надо советовать нехорошее в части "советовал смотреть"

Comment: @tocic предлагаете делать слияние перед слиянием? Что это даст?

Comment: @PavelMayorov имеется в виду, что после того как первую ветку вмержили в мастер, можно сделать ребейз второй ветки на текущий мастер. Это даст бесконфликтный мерж этой второй ветки в мастер.

Comment: @LazyBadger аргументируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: TBD - это на выбор или "редкие, возможно огромные (потому что редкие), но чистые коммиты" или "быстрые грязные коммиты в транк и падающие тесты на CI". Третьего не дано, если только девелопят не волшебники: бранчи не просто так из пижонства придумали, а в частности еще и для изоляции влияния. @tocic - я все эти грабли видел и старательно прибирал еще во времена SVN *дцать лет тому как

Comment: @LazyBadger слишком сильное заявление. Конечно, можно неправильно использовать модели, но это не делает их нехорошими. По ссылке сказано, что эта модель не отказывается от короткоживущих веток и предполагает короткие И чистые коммиты с CI. А также то, что она используется в Google, например, где десятки тысяч разработчиков и миллионы строк кода, и то, что её модификация является дефолтной моделью на GitHub. Вряд ли так много пользующихся ей разработчиков являются волшебниками. P.S.: возможно, вы с чем-то путаете эту модель, т.к. спецификация относительно недавно появилась.

Comment: @LazyBadger Что-то у вас не сходится. Огромные коммиты крайне сложно сделать чистыми, вероятность конфликтов и, соответственно, сложность мерджев повышается, а ревью усложняется. Также обычно подразумеваетя, что CI должно давать обратную свять как можно быстрее, и падающие тесты CI при коммите в транк в день внесения изменений лучше, чем падающие тесты через неделю, когда туда отправится огромный редкий коммит.

Comment: @user7860670 - у меня все сходится, я **практик**, а не *читатель сайтиков*

Comment: @LazyBadger Однако ваши заявления про "огромные чистые коммиты" расходятся с практикой и здравым смыслом.

Comment: @tocic - [сюрпрайз в натуре!!!](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/#history)"Trunk-Based Development — это не новая модель ветвления...
Это была менее известная модель ветвления с середины девяностых, а с тактической точки зрения - с восьмидесятых". Ладно, идите по своим граблям сами! Это будет еще одно "открытие" зумеров, после переоткрытия общаг и авосек, я ушел

Answer (score 2):

Действительно как же так получается))

1. Сливаете первую ветку с мастером локально(что бы внести в вашу ветку изменения с мастера и локально разрешить конфликты). Пушите свою ветку, что бы она обновилась удаленно(теперь на вашей удаленной ветке хранится объединенная локальная ветка с изменениями и мастер актуальный). Делаете медж в мастер вашей удаленной ветки на сервере(тут не возникнет конфликтов т.к. вы их все разрешили локально и все изменения сохранятся).
2. После того как соединили мастер и первую ветку. Владелец второй ветки сливает себе изменения на локальный мастер(что бы получить ваши залитые изменения). Локально делает мердж мастера в свою ветку(что-бы разрешить конфликты локально). Пушит свою локальную ветку в удаленную(публикация). Делаете медж в удаленный мастер с вашей второй веткой(на мастере окажется его ветка содержащая вашу ветку, которая содержит мастер). Все по принципу матрешки)
   и т.д.

P.S. Если вы все будете сливать свои ветки с мастером без его постоянного обновления на локальных копиях, логично что все изменения с предыдущих веток затрутся.

Answer (score -1):

1. Гейм-дизайнеры именно для Unity (и прочего с кучей бинарников в работе) сильно форсят няшность Plastic SCM (сам не пробовал, мнения не имею), смотреть можно начинать отсюда https://unity.com/solutions/version-control-artists
2. Как уже отметил @tocic, перед 2+ мержем в master, надо синхронизировать feature-branches мержем **из master** в каждый из них. И аккуратно подбирать, чуть ли пальцем в небо, (diff|merge)tool и merge-policy, чтобы не убивать бинари с одной стороны слияния полностью (готового рецепта у меня нет)

Comment: Plastick SCM пробовали, но потом с нас денюжку попросили:)